# How to print a WinForm which contains a scrollDown panel?

Tags: c#, winforms, printing

I have a panel that displays database information in labels (a lot of labels).
Now, the labels extend the size of the panel and you need to scroll down to see them all. Everything is working, and you can see the labels if you scroll down.

How do I print the form and the panel with all its content? I tried to capture the screen, but it's bigger than the screen.

Is there a function like `panel.printAllContent().IntoAnA4Paper;`?

Comment: This of course doesn't work.  There's little point in pursuing this anyway, screen dumps are ugly.  Use PrintDocument or a report generator like RDLC or Crystal Reports.  Many others to choose from.

Comment: it's not my desission to make

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's the right way. As you said you display information taken from a database so you already have your data model. You should print the data, not the interface.

But, if you want to print the UI, I think you should first put the interface inside a Bitmap, and then print the Bitmap.

Here's a link with an example: http://www.codeproject.com/Answers/200887/How-to-print-part-of-the-window-form-in-c-window-a#answer4

Comment: the problem is i'm taking data from 5 diff places including 3 DB and thay must have the winform printed i dont care about the size i have a A3 printer Even a plotter so the size dosent metter i just need to find a way to scrool during printing and add it to a big pic